# How to start learning WinWrap Basic for SPSS 15.0?

Tags: spss, winwrap

Due to some reasons we use SPSS 15.0 in the company I work in. This version does not support Python so I want to learn WinWrap Basic. Anyway, not a single person use and/or know WWB so I need to learn it by myself. Does anyone here know how to start except using built-in guides?

Comment: You can do quite a lot with spss macro (can't say though if version 15 already had that) - look up `define - !enddefine`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Python support began with V14, but you have to install Python and the plugin separately.  IIRC, it was Python 2.6 back then.  However, I don't know where you could find the plugin that old anymore.  If you have your installation materials, look through that information.

For Basic, there is help in the Script menu on the language and on the SPSS apis.  However, that api help will not work on recent Windows versions due to unhappy things that Microsoft has done with those versions.